# How to get a unit of measurement as a singular noun?

Tags: ios, swift, localization

I'm trying to represent running *pace* in my app - let's say 5min/km.

For voice over, I'd love this to be read as *five minutes per kilomete**r***.

I know I can get *kilometer**s*** like that:

```
let measurementFormatter = MeasurementFormatter()
measurementFormatter.unitStyle = .long
measurementFormatter.string(from: UnitLength.kilometers)
```

but would it be possible to get the singular form (and take advantage of the already localized units)?

Comment: you want TextToSpeech ??

Comment: you mean 12km/h

Comment: @Sumit_VE I want to use this text for a11y and voice over!

Comment: @LeoDabus note that it's time/distance ("pace"), not distance/time ("speed") - but it doesn't really matter for what I'm asking.

Comment: It does matter, since I think there is a built-in unitSpeed that will give you "kilometers per hour". But I don't think there is a built-in unitPace as you would use for running, like "minutes per kilometer"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the only native way to do this would be create an explicit measurement and manually remove the singular unit ("1"):

```swift
let measurementFormatter = MeasurementFormatter()
measurementFormatter.unitStyle = .long
measurementFormatter.unitOptions = .providedUnit

let length: Measurement<UnitLength> = .init(value: 1, unit: .kilometers)
let str = measurementFormatter.string(from: length)
  .replacingOccurrences(of: "1", with: "")
  .replacingOccurrences(of: "  ", with: " ")
  .trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces)
```

I'm no language expert but I expect this will work with most (if not all) languages.

Comment: I was thinking something similar - but I really wanted to avoid that `.filter` (or similar). Thanks for your answer though, most probably I'll accept it if nothing else comes up!

Comment: @phi Agreed it's not the ideal solution, however you could build your own "thin" caching layer for strings of this kind and only have to compute it once.

Answer (score -3):

### Edit

It looks like it's possible to create a custom MeasurementFormatter that outputs in minutes/km or minutes/mile. See the tutorial at https://www.raywenderlich.com/553-how-to-make-an-app-like-runkeeper-part-1 for an example of how to do this.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'm trying to get the singular noun "kilometer" (not "kilometers").

Comment: So he is. And are you using UnitSpeed?